# Example of infinite extension of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: field-theory

Isn't any extension of $\mathbb{R}$ either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Any algebraic extension is. You can always add transcendentals.

Comment: But isn't any element of $\mathbb{C}$ algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the variable potato is not an element of $\mathbb C$, and $\mathbb R(\mathrm{potato})$ is a perfectly fine extension of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course there are plenty of infinite extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ -- as large as you like.

The most commonly studied example would be $\mathbb{R}(t)$, where $t$ is a new variable. This is the field of rational functions (a polynomial over a polynomial) in $t$. This is an infinite extension of $\mathbb{R}$.

We can make ever larger extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ by taking $\mathbb{R}(t_1, t_2, t_3, \ldots t_k)$, or even $\mathbb{R}(T)$ where $T$ is some countable, or uncountable, or larger set of new variables.
This will be the set of expressions $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials in those variables.

Another example is the [Hyperreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number). This is an uncountable field containing the real numbers that is nevertheless much larger, including infinitesimal and infinite numbers.

In general, **your intuition should be to assume that arbitrarily large objects of a certain kind will exist**, rather than to assume otherwise. This is the case with almost every object you have probably heard of: groups, rings, fields, totally ordered sets, vector spaces, topological spaces, metric spaces, and so on. Specifically, if there is an infinite object of that kind, and the definition of such objects is simple enough (first-order, but don't worry about that) then there will be examples of that object of arbitrary large size. This is a basic result in model theory.

Comment: Mandatory plug for the Field of surreal numbers!

Comment: @PatrickStevens Almost mentioned it, but decided to avoid the possibility of fields which are not sets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @6005 is great, but I also wanna add the quaternion field $\mathbb H$, which could be consider as an extension of $\mathbb R$:

$$\mathbb H=\mathbb R[i,j,k]$$

where

$$i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$$

and such other rules of this type.

It is just one example among many others.

Comment: I think the convention that fields must be commutative is most prevalent, under which the quaternions are not a field, but I'm aware that some people do not make the commutativity requirement.

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: @ZevChonoles I certainly only know of the quaternions as a division ring.